# Ffmpeg [NULL @ 0x56390335ae80] Unable to find a suitable output format for 'listen' listen: Invalid argument

Tags: ffmpeg

I am trying to record a live stream using ffmpeg. I am using an sdp file as input and trying to put it in a .mp3 file and i get the following error:

```
ffmpeg listen  -loglevel debug -protocol_whitelist file,crypto,udp,rtp,tcp  -i audio.sdp -f mp3 output.mp3
ffmpeg version 3.4.8-0ubuntu0.2 Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 7 (Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=0ubuntu0.2 --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librubberband --enable-librsvg --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libopencv --enable-libx264 --enable-shared
  libavutil      55. 78.100 / 55. 78.100
  libavcodec     57.107.100 / 57.107.100
  libavformat    57. 83.100 / 57. 83.100
  libavdevice    57. 10.100 / 57. 10.100
  libavfilter     6.107.100 /  6.107.100
  libavresample   3.  7.  0 /  3.  7.  0
  libswscale      4.  8.100 /  4.  8.100
  libswresample   2.  9.100 /  2.  9.100
  libpostproc    54.  7.100 / 54.  7.100
Splitting the commandline.
Reading option 'listen' ... matched as output url.
Reading option '-loglevel' ... matched as option 'loglevel' (set logging level) with argument 'debug'.
Reading option '-protocol_whitelist' ... matched as AVOption 'protocol_whitelist' with argument 'file,crypto,udp,rtp,tcp'.
Reading option '-i' ... matched as input url with argument 'audio.sdp'.
Reading option '-f' ... matched as option 'f' (force format) with argument 'mp3'.
Reading option 'output.mp3' ... matched as output url.
Finished splitting the commandline.
Parsing a group of options: global .
Applying option loglevel (set logging level) with argument debug.
Successfully parsed a group of options.
Parsing a group of options: input url audio.sdp.
Successfully parsed a group of options.
Opening an input file: audio.sdp.
[NULL @ 0x5639033039c0] Opening 'audio.sdp' for reading
[sdp @ 0x5639033039c0] Format sdp probed with size=2048 and score=50
[sdp @ 0x5639033039c0] audio codec set to: opus
[sdp @ 0x5639033039c0] audio samplerate set to: 48000
[sdp @ 0x5639033039c0] audio channels set to: 2
[sdp @ 0x5639033039c0] audio codec set to: opus
[sdp @ 0x5639033039c0] audio samplerate set to: 16000
[sdp @ 0x5639033039c0] audio channels set to: 1
[sdp @ 0x5639033039c0] audio codec set to: opus
[sdp @ 0x5639033039c0] audio samplerate set to: 32000
[sdp @ 0x5639033039c0] audio channels set to: 1
[sdp @ 0x5639033039c0] audio codec set to: opus
[sdp @ 0x5639033039c0] audio samplerate set to: 8000
[sdp @ 0x5639033039c0] audio channels set to: 1
[udp @ 0x56390330b3c0] end receive buffer size reported is 131072
[udp @ 0x56390330b5e0] end receive buffer size reported is 131072
[sdp @ 0x5639033039c0] setting jitter buffer size to 500
[sdp @ 0x5639033039c0] Before avformat_find_stream_info() pos: 1281 bytes read:1281 seeks:0 nb_streams:1
[sdp @ 0x5639033039c0] After avformat_find_stream_info() pos: 1281 bytes read:1281 seeks:0 frames:0
Input #0, sdp, from 'audio.sdp':
  Metadata:
    title           : -
  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0, 0, 1/8000: Audio: opus, 48000 Hz, mono, fltp
Successfully opened the file.
Parsing a group of options: output url listen.
Successfully parsed a group of options.
Opening an output file: listen.
[NULL @ 0x56390335ae80] Unable to find a suitable output format for 'listen'
listen: Invalid argument
[AVIOContext @ 0x56390330c6c0] Statistics: 1281 bytes read, 0 seeks
```

I have tried with output as .wav file too, but i get the same error, Please help me out. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What's the `listen` meant to do?

Comment: It  is used to receive an RTMP stream.  I am trying to save a live audio that is being streamed in my prosody server.

Comment: Your command receives a stream via RTSP, not RTMP and it does so via the means of a SDP file, which has no option called `-listen`. The closest is `-listen_timeout`. Is that what you meant?

Comment: Even after i use -listen_timeout i get the exact error, which is: Opening an output file: listen_timeout.
[NULL @ 0x5576fbd6ee80] Unable to find a suitable output format for 'listen_timeout'
listen_timeout: Invalid argument